# unable to install windows SDK for windows 7 enterprise

Tags: windows-7, installation, registry, registrykey

I am trying to install "Microsoft® Windows® Software Development Kit for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1." (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138). However, as I attempt the compiler installation I keep getting the following error:

```
An error occurred installing the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 Intellidocs package. Error: 'Microsoft' is not a valid short file name.
```

I understand this error is fairly common in Windows Vista and 7, and yet Microsoft offers no solution (their diagnostic/repair tools can't find any problem, even though the problem exists). From the workarounds I found online, they all require changing a key in the key registry, but the key that needs to be changed is different for every error (different short file names can be missing).

My question is the following:
1) Where is this "Microsoft" key supposed to be in the registry? I can't tell if I am missing it entirely or if it is pointing to a wrong location since I don't know where in the registry to look for it
2) What is the correct value this key is supposed to be pointing too?

Answer (score 0):

There could just be problems with the Windows Installer. Try repairing the Windows Installer Service, then repeat. This is just one fix that may work.

Comment: Note: I know you used the diagnostic tools to try to repair it, but this sometimes doesn't work. Check out this link for another way to fix it: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/159447-windows-installer-simple-fix-worked-me.html